# Expectiing error when I use incorrect type in generic

Tags: typescript

I setup an example with these types

```
class IRequest<R>{}

export class ExampleCommandResult{
    gg2:string;
}
export class ExampleCommandResult2{
    gg:string;
}
export default class ExampleCommand extends IRequest<ExampleCommandResult>{}

type Handler<T extends IRequest<O>, O> = (value: T) => O
```

Then I use the handler with `ExampleCommandResult2` instead of `ExampleCommandResult`

```
const handler: Handler<ExampleCommand, ExampleCommandResult2> = (v:ExampleCommand) => {
    return new ExampleCommandResult2();
}
```

I expect an error because `ExampleCommand` is `IRequest<ExampleCommandResult>` but I used `Handler<ExampleCommand, ExampleCommandResult2>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're observing here is due to TypeScript using a [Structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), as opposed to a [Nominal type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), which is what something like Java uses.

In short, what this means is that TypeScript considers 2 types to be equal if the structure of the types is equivalent, i.e. if each of the properties of the respective types are also "equal".

So when typescript is resolving the type `ExampleCommand`, as both `IRequest` and `ExampleCommand` have no properties or methods, this effectively resolves to `{}`. So regardless of the value of the type parameter, the type of `IRequest<R>` will be `{}`.

You will see that as soon as you start introducing methods or properties that depend on the type parameter `R`, errors will start to appear. So if you were to write this for example:

```
class IRequest<R>{
  foo: R | null = null;
}
```

An error appears in the declaration of `handler` with the following error:

```
Type 'ExampleCommand' does not satisfy the constraint 'IRequest<ExampleCommandResult2>'.
  Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
    Type 'ExampleCommandResult | null' is not assignable to type 'ExampleCommandResult2 | null'.
      Property 'gg' is missing in type 'ExampleCommandResult' but required in type 'ExampleCommandResult2'.ts(2344)
001.ts(9, 3): 'gg' is declared here.
```

Comment: The pupose of my types was to specify a type along IRequest (the type returned by the request). So I don't use R in IRequest. Do you know if there is another way, or a trick ?

Comment: I want to replicate types from C# but I'm not sure it's possible anymore ... https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/c1ad66ef52434a22c10a0de5e060d13b185ef80b/src/MediatR/IRequestHandler.cs

Comment: I used `private _internal:R | null = null;` Thank you for your help